# Hazelcast event listener with predicates

Tags: java, events, hazelcast

I need to listen to a HZ update event ONLY when an specific property of the object changes:

https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.1/data-structures/map#listening-to-map-entries-with-predicates

But I dont know if this could be done through a Predicate (see bold fragment):

> map.addEntryListener(chatsWithConvView, **Predicates.sql("")**, true);

If the property stays the same, and all other properties of the object changes I dont want the event to be triggered because of millions of events would be trigered.

Is this possible?

Unfortunately, this doesnt work, but could be something like this:

> map.addEntryListener(chatsWithConvView,
> Predicates.sql("waConversationsCounter = (SELECT
> 'waConversationsCounter' + 1)"), true);

I know this waConversationsCounter is always going to increment 1 (always), is the only update event I want to capture. But this predicate doesnt work.

How can I do it?

Comment: Is upgrading a possibility ? 5.* onwards allows trhe use of Jet processing map journals, so you have the old and new values and can include/exclude baed on logic you determine

Comment: thanks, for now is not possible, so we abandoned the idea, and took another ideas.